# можно ли создать переменные цвета в svg файле?

Tags: pyqt5

В данном примере имеется переопределение класса QtWidgets.QPushButton в Button

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    left_click = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    right_click = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.left_click.emit()
        elif event.button() == Qt.Qt.RightButton:
            self.right_click.emit()
            
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        #super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn = Button('Нажми меня')
        self.btn.left_click.connect(self.left_click)
        self.btn.right_click.connect(self.right_click)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
    def right_click(self):
        print('right click')
    def left_click(self):
        print('left click')
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Имею иконку в .svg формате:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#E00000ff">
<path fill="#E00000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 41.01 42.01 C 83.34 41.99 125.67 41.99 167.99 42.01 C 168.01 84.00 168.01 125.99 167.99 167.99 C 125.66 168.01 83.33 168.01 41.01 167.99 C 40.99 126.00 40.99 84.00 41.01 42.01 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

могу ли я считывая файл переопределять цвет данной иконки? (как-то так...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#%MY_COLOR%">
<path fill="#%MY_COLOR%" opacity="1.00" d=" M 41.01 42.01 C 83.34 41.99 125.67 41.99 167.99 42.01 C 168.01 84.00 168.01 125.99 167.99 167.99 C 125.66 168.01 83.33 168.01 41.01 167.99 C 40.99 126.00 40.99 84.00 41.01 42.01 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Можете. А тот SVG как-то используется в программе?

Comment: только как иконка, но хотелось бы сделать 2 варианта цветной (два цвета) и одноцветный для всех иконок приложения.

Comment: А как именно используете в приложении? Покажите код. Насчет замены цвета это не сложно -- загрузить файл и сделать `replace` на свой цвет. А с тем как это после использовать -- вопрос :)